# how to select a row in a table with Selenium IDE

Tags: select, selenium, row, selenium-ide

i want to select a row in a table and then continue with the Next button of the form,but when i execute the line

```
click  |  //div[@id='grilleRepresentant']/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/span
```

i have an error.

Comment: can you please share HTML of that row??

Comment: Hi, here is a part of the table HTML : <div class="t-grid-header"><div class="t-grid-header-wrap"><table cellspacing="0"><colgroup><col><col><col><col><col><col>.....and this is the row HTML: <tr classe="t-alt  t-state -selected">...is the second line of the table.